# .htaccess rewrite remote image location

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

with .htaccess below i can rewrite image location from *http//mysite/folder/test.jpg* to *http//mysite/test.jpg*

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pic.jpg /folder/pic.jpg
```

but when i tried with remote site

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^img.jpg http/remotesite/img.jpg
```

i can't rewrite it to http//mysite/img.jpg because its redirected to original location and my question is, it is possible to rewrite remote image location with .htaccess?

thanks

**SOLVED**

using php readfile()

```
 <?php
 header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
 $img = $_GET['img'];
 $url =  "http://remote/image.php?img=".$img;
 readfile("$url");
 ?>
```

and .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(*.jpg)$ images.php?img=$1[L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^img.jpg http://remotesite/img.jpg` - not something as simple as the http:// is it?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? How many sites do you have and can you give example on what should be rewrited to what? Thx

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^img.jpg http://remotesite/img.jpg
```